# Cypress failing with CircleCI 2.0 and Permission denied while Unarchiving cache

Tags: angular, circleci, cypress

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
       - image: cypress/base:10
      - image: circleci/node:10.15.3
    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run: npm ci
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      # run tests!
      - run: npm run e2e
      # build apps!
      - run: npm run affected:build -- --all
```

[image: Error]

First I had a issue of cypress not running with Circle CI, I added  - image: cypress/base:10 to the docker and it got resolved. Now as shown in the screenshot above there seems to be permission issue related to cache,I'm working on how to fix it and I also need some help to fix it.
Thank you.

Comment: You're using `circleci/node:10.15.3`, *not* the Cypress container from the orb definition. Re-read the guidance on using the orb: https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/cypress-io/cypress

Comment: Added  - image: cypress/base:10 to docker and test was success. Now checking with another issue "Restoring cache fails with "Permission Denied"

Comment: Then [edit] to give a [mcve] that would recreate the new issue.

Comment: Thank you, done.